# Use GVim as GNU OCtave's text editor on Windows

Tags: vim, octave

I am using Windows 10 and the text editor I am used to is Vim. I just intalled a shiny new GNU Octave copy (version 7.2.0). The Octave editor is pretty limited and I know it is possible to override it to **vim/gvim**. I have tried different things to make it work, without success.

**Using the Preference->Editor pane**

[image: Preference window]

It seems that Octave is never able to understand what I put in there. I have tried using **gvim**, **gvim.exe**, a full path to my copy of gvim, etc. When I go to the editor, I either get:

[image: Error from GUI (1)]

or, when using a full path to the editor (ex. here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\gvim.exe`):

[image: Error from GUI (2)]

I think Octave is unable to deal with spaces in paths (at least from this edit box). It have also tried using single and double quotes, but it also fails:

[image: Error from GUI (3)]

**Using an .octaverc file**

When nothing worked in the GUI, I tried configuring an `.octaverc` file, as described in the [GNU Octave Wiki](https://wiki.octave.org/Vim):

```matlab
 edit mode sync
 edit home .
 EDITOR('gvim')
```

I tried with **vim** as well, full paths, etc, to no avail. Now I know that this file is read and executed when lauching Octave because when I put garbage in it, I see it in the Command Window. I also found a **Set Path** option in the GUI and I tried adding the path to **gvim** there, but it had no effect:

[image: Set Path]

**Question**

I can I make my GNU Octave editor gvim, on Windows? I would like to use my current installation (default for Octave, default for Vim as well...)

Comment: Why the close flag? How can I improve it?

Comment: If you suspect that spaces are the issue, you could maybe try to install vim into a different directory that does not contain any spaces in the path. Have you tried that?

Comment: @flawr Yes I could try that, but I would like to be able to make it work with both default installations...

Comment: I don't say this should be your final solution, but it would tell us whether spaces are the issue or not. If they are the issue we'd have to think about a different approach alltogether!